# Load GeoJSON data onto Leaflet Map using Slippy Map formatted URL

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tiles, slippy

I've been trying to get some GeoJSON polygon data to show up on a Leaflet map, but the endpoint I'm fetching the data from answers to the format `/api/{z}/{x}/{y}.geojson`. Leaflet has support for GeoJSON (as well as slicing GeoJSON via the VectorGrid plugin) but only takes Slippy Map tiles in png format, like:

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: <access token>
}).addTo(map);
```

What's the best way to read in GeoJSON from a tile endpoint like this in Leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for the [Leaflet GeoJSON Tile Layer](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/) plugin:

> Renders GeoJSON tiles on an L.GeoJSON layer.
>
> […] shows how to render a GeoJSON Tile Layer for a tile endpoint at `http://tile.example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.json`

There are also many other [Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) that might fit your need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! While this technically works, it's been deprecated past Leaflet 1.0.0 (or at least, I couldn't get it to work on Leaflet latest, but 0.7.x worked without a problem). I was hoping that there was a newer tiling plugin that could handle it.

Comment: If you can provide a public tile source for test, maybe we could have a look.

Comment: FWIW I have published a Proof of Concept of a plugin version for Leaflet 1+ in the plugin repo [issue #39](https://github.com/glenrobertson/leaflet-tilelayer-geojson/issues/39)

Comment: Nice! Shame you can't find a proper tileserver to test it out on though... I was using a private tileserver when I encountered this issue, so I unfortunately can't share it.